How do the LDS confirm the first vision/Moroni without having anything to test it against?
I've been looking more and more into the Church of later day saints. I'm obviously not a member, but I am curious about them all the same.
My question is about how it appears as if the majority of their answers regarding the first vision* or their angel Moroni are sourced from those entities themselves.
Edit: *The first vision as far as I know was experienced only by Joseph Smith.
How do Christians discern between genuine dreams & visions from God and false dreams & visions from a different source (flesh, enemy)?
I saw this answer regarding how the LDS are supposed to determine if a vision, angel, etc is from good or evil. And I agree that if the original source was valid, it would all be okay.
But from my understanding all the sources listed by the LDS answer are in and of themselves from the beliefs delivered by Moroni or aligned with them in new teachings.
How does an LDS believer know these teachings are valid in the first place and not trick? (Or is this the faith part?)
Edit: For clarity, I'm not asking for the current teachings of the LDS, I'm asking how is the basis of the LDS faith confirmed as "divine" before their teachings confirmed it?
For example: An angel gives you a special book, the book says the angel is definitely not evil. (A proves B, B proves A) How do you prove the source is valid without using the source's own claim?

Based on comments/edits the real question is how did Joseph Smith know/validate the visions that he was involved with when there was no LDS doctrine/teachings on the subject yet.
1 John 4:1-3

1 Dear friends, do not believe every spirit, but test the spirits to see whether they are from God, because many false prophets have gone out into the world.
2 This is how you can recognize the Spirit of God: Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God,
3 but every spirit that does not acknowledge Jesus is not from God. This is the spirit of the antichrist, which you have heard is coming and even now is already in the world.

The teachings of Joseph Smith, the Book of Mormon, and future prophets affirm that Jesus is the Christ and that he "came in the flesh" as prophesied and affirmed in scripture. For satan/demon to inspire these principles goes counter to Christ's own teachings (Matt 12:25-26, Matthew 9:33–34, Mark 3:22–30, Luke 11:14–26, explanation of these scriptures can be found in Jesus the Christ, by James E Talmage)
So when Joseph Smith has the first vision (JSH 1:17)

17 It no sooner appeared than I found myself delivered from the enemy which held me bound. When the light rested upon me I saw two Personages, whose brightness and glory defy all description, standing above me in the air. One of them spake unto me, calling me by name and said, pointing to the other—This is My Beloved Son. Hear Him!

This is acknowledging that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh and from God (Matt 3:17, Mark 1:1)
When Moroni visited Joseph Smith (JSH 1:40)

40 In addition to these, he quoted the eleventh chapter of Isaiah, saying that it was about to be fulfilled. He quoted also the third chapter of Acts, twenty-second and twenty-third verses, precisely as they stand in our New Testament. He said that that prophet was Christ; but the day had not yet come when “they who would not hear his voice should be cut off from among the people,” but soon would come.

Again, another spirit acknowledging that Jesus is the Christ. Satan wouldn't have done that.
The Book of Mormon's (Another Testament of Jesus Christ) title page states:

And also to the convincing of the Jew and Gentile that Jesus is the Christ, the Eternal God, manifesting himself unto all nations

Again, the purpose is to convince mankind that Jesus is the Christ. If Moroni were Satan or one of Satan's ministers acting as an instrument of evil, he surely would not have done so much to convince mankind to believe in Christ; it goes counter to Satan's purpose (see Matt 12:25).
Additionally as pointed out by Joseph Fielding McConkie in Sons and daughters of God:

Many a pretender to the prophetic office has claimed to entertain angels or to have spoken with God, but who other than Joseph Smith introduced his angels to others? Joseph Smith introduced Moroni to Oliver Cowdery, David Whitmer, and Martin Harris. He was never alone when priesthood or keys were restored.... He and Sydney Rigdon received the revelation on the degrees of glory together. Together they saw legions of angels, along with the Father and the Son (see D&C 76:21–23). Oliver Cowdery was with Joseph Smith when John the Baptist came to restore the Aaronic Priesthood, and when Peter, James, and John came to restore the Melchizedek Priesthood. Oliver was also with Joseph Smith when Christ came to accept the dedication of the Kirtland Temple, and Moses, Elias, and Elijah restored their keys, powers, and authorities.

Related:

Is It Revelation?, by Elder Lund 1997
answer to: Why does the church of latter day saints not recognize the obvious sin of the angel Moroni according to the account of Joseph Smith's own words?
Moroni's Visit/Angel of Satan, FAIR (unofficial LDS apologetic site)
God's Compelling Witness: The Book of Mormon, Elder Tad Callister, Oct 2017 (in regards to knowing by fruit)


A more modern example of LDS prophets/apostles acknowledging that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh and is from God, is The Living Christ

...None other has had so profound an influence upon all who have lived and will yet live upon the earth.
...Under the direction of His Father, He was the creator of the earth.
...
We solemnly testify that His life, which is central to all human history, neither began in Bethlehem nor concluded on Calvary. He was the Firstborn of the Father, the Only Begotten Son in the flesh, the Redeemer of the world.
...
We bear testimony, as His duly ordained Apostles—that Jesus is the Living Christ, the immortal Son of God.

emphasis mine

I think everybody who was in the comment thread read all the comments.  @Matthew you know this isn't the place to score points against another group. The only good comments ask for clarification of the content.  I'd suggest the chat but it's been little dead lately, I think people are too busy concentrating on things of this world.
